# Any Fast Charge Kernel for Nexus 7 grouper? Franco Kernel?

Tags: root-access, kernel

I have the latest Franco kernel on my N7 2012 WiFi, normally it should be able to fast charge but I cant? Anyone have a solution or another kernel supporting fast charge for my device?

This wont effect multibooting right?